# Python function ignores variable change

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a basic 2 screen application with python, and am switching screens by changing a variable (yes I am aware that this is a really bad way to make an app) I am using pygame

I have a basic main function that detects when a key is down, then sets the variable to 2, and then runs my draw function, that has an if statement for if the variable is 1 or 2. Renders a different thing.

My issue is that even with the event changing the variable (and then printing that variable verifying it changed) my output doesn't change, I can change the variable I set as my default value and it changes to the other screen, but it refuses to change from the event.

```
import pygame
import time
import datetime
from pygame import freetype

screen = 1   <<-- My default value for the screen

FPS = 15

WHITE = (220, 220, 220)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 480, 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("test")
FONT = pygame.freetype.Font("FiraSans-Medium.ttf", 150)


def draw():   <<-- Draw Function
    if screen == 1:
        print("screen 1")
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%I:%M")
        WIN.fill(WHITE)
        FONT.render_to(WIN, (20, 160), current_time, (0, 0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
    if screen == 2:
        print("screen 2")
        WIN.fill(WHITE)
        FONT.render_to(WIN, (20, 160), "screen 2", (0, 0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: <<-- Event to change the screen
                screen = 2
                print(screen)

        draw()  <<-- Call draw function

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You need to tell the main function that it's a global variable, otherwise it is treated as a local variable by default.  Put `global screen` at the top of main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function thinks screen is a local variable, only usable in the function. Put `global screen` at the top of the function to tell the function that screen, is a global variable, and modify the global value.